# Secure string output and preserve spaces

Tags: html, angular

In Angular, I use the string output method

```html
<div>{{stringWithValue}}</div>
```

But if my string contains only a whitespace or nothing, the value is not rendered. As a solution, I can use the following:

```html
&nbsp;
```

for plain html. Now I prepare the following code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ra8pe4

```html
<div>{{stringWithValue}}</div>
<div>{{stringEmpty}}</div>
<div>{{stringWithValue}}</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>{{stringWithValue}}</div>
```

StringEmpty returns a space and I try to use special character **reserved space** automatically to prevent my layout.

Is there a common approach?

Comment: This is unpredictable i usually use css classes to achieve this

Comment: your stringEmpty is rendered in the dom as I see in your example. But a div with empty content does not have height. So if you do use css to set a fixed height or min-height. This might be a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution based on your comments about CSS:

```css
div:empty::before {
  content: "\200b"; /* unicode zero width space character */
}
```

For pure whitespace output, there is a problem, but this does not affect my application.